# bazel `java_test` rule - test.xml only exits on failed shard?

Tags: bazel, bazel-java

Trying to run `bazel test ...` with remote execution and `java_test` rule.

My test sometimes succeeded, sometimes failed. This is another story.

But I want to get test.xml for all cases to check elapsed time for each test.
test.xml exists on `bazel-testlogs` only when some shard failed.

I tried

> bazel test --test_output=all --test_summary=detailed ...

but didn't worked.

How can I get all test.xml even if it succeed?

Answer (score 1):

`bazel test --remote_download_toplevel ...` worked for me.

[remote_execution_test.sh](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/test/shell/bazel/remote/remote_execution_test.sh#L1485-L1535) from bazel repo gave me clue!